# If a dragonborn uses fire breathing with a stomach full of alcohol, what happens?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, food-and-drink

I'm having an argument that my intestines would explode if I tried to breath fire as a dragonborn, after drinking alcohol.

What would happen?

Comment: By asking *am I tight*, are you spelling the word *right* incorrectly, or are you making a joke about 'getting tight' which is an old expression for getting drunk?  Alcohol to drink appears to be related to your question.  Please clear that up so that you can get a useful answer. Welcome to RPGSE. the [Tour], the [help], [ask] and [answer] are useful for getting the most out of an SE site.

Comment: Hi, Ddpasty, and welcome to RPG.SE! I found your question a little hard to read and understand, so I would suggest making an [edit] to clarify what you mean. Hope you stick around!

Comment: I meant right but I was typing too fast and tapped t instead of r

Comment: I'm still struggling to identify the precise question. It doesn't help that the title of the question seems to have been cut off. Is your question something along the lines of "If a dragonborn drinks a lot of strong alcohol then breathes fires, do they explode?" Or maybe, based on your previous edit, "Can a dragonborn use alcohol to enhance their fire breath?"

Answer (score 5):

## Alcohol does not affect fire breath

The Rules As Written don't describe any effect on dragonborn fire breath from alcohol.  Your DM could choose to issue a house rule if they wanted, but otherwise there is no effect.

## Also, most booze is not even flammable

Alcoholic drinks don't even burn unless they're at least 40% alcohol (80 proof).  Beer and wine are less than that.  If you drank something very high in alcohol content, your DM would probably rule that you'd get alcohol poisoning before you got an effect on your fire breath.

You've specified that the booze is "elves foot mead".  Wikipedia tells us that the alcohol content of mead "ranges from about 3.5% ABV[4] to more than 18%" which is still way less than 40%.  The mead is not flammable and definitely will not explode.

Comment: it takes a 50:50 mix by volume to create a steady flame, or a 42%+ volume alcohol and a 'wick' of sugar (for example Rum or Absinth are used like this in flaming drinks)